# Approval workflow without Sharepoint designer, flow and power apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

Is it possible to build Approval workflow without Sharepoint designer, flow and power apps. I have criteria like in what conditions it has to whom?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can apply a native workflow on item or library by making a right click on the item that you want to apply on it the flow then hover on **Flow** then select **Configure flows** and the property pane will be opened then choice **Content Approval** and then click on **Save**.

Comment: Is it possible to make multi level approval workflow? Mail trigger, document approval and periodic reminders?

Comment: You can't do all of that with this native way, you need to use Flow or ShrePoint Designer(NB : Deprecated by Microsoft) or any Third party tools. Except document approval as i show you with this native way above.

Comment: You can use SharePoint OOTB approval Workflow. it can have multiple level of approval, either in series or parallel.https://support.office.com/en-us/article/all-about-approval-workflows-078c5a89-821f-44a9-9530-40bb34f9f742